# npm run start, Failed at the start script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

This is my first time using nodejs, I am getting the following error while running `npm run start` command. Is there a version compatibility issue between node and npm? I can see that the end lines suggesting this is not an issue with npm.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/home/iamuser/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/iamuser/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.15
3 info using node@v14.17.6
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle test-api@1.0.0~prestart: test-api@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle test-api@1.0.0~start: test-api@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle test-api@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle test-api@1.0.0~start: PATH: /home/iamuser/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/iamuser/Documents/JS/rapid_api/test-api/node_modules/.bin:/home/iamuser/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/bin:/home/iamuser/anaconda3/bin:/home/iamuser/anaconda3/condabin:/home/iamuser/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle test-api@1.0.0~start: CWD: /home/iamuser/Documents/JS/rapid_api/test-api
10 silly lifecycle test-api@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'nodemon index.js' ]
11 info lifecycle test-api@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
12 verbose stack Error: test-api@1.0.0 start: `nodemon index.js`
12 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/iamuser/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
13 verbose pkgid test-api@1.0.0
14 verbose cwd /home/iamuser/Documents/JS/rapid_api/test-api
15 verbose Linux 5.11.0-44-generic
16 verbose argv "/home/iamuser/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/bin/node" "/home/iamuser/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/bin/npm" "run" "start"
17 verbose node v14.17.6
18 verbose npm  v6.14.15
19 error code ELIFECYCLE
20 error syscall spawn
21 error file sh
22 error errno ENOENT
23 error test-api@1.0.0 start: `nodemon index.js`
23 error spawn ENOENT
24 error Failed at the test-api@1.0.0 start script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "iamuser",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.10",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please, provide the `package.json` file?

Comment: Try running `npm install` then `npm run start`. I'm guessing that `nodemon` is not installed yet

Comment: @GuillermoGonzález I just updated package.json in the description

Comment: @ndemasie I did run `npm install`

Comment: @ndemasie you were right, nodemon was not installed, I tried `npm install nodemon` and it worked!

Comment: @palash, run `npm list -g --depth=0` if you don't see `nodemon` then run `npm install -g nodemon`

Comment: @ndemasie it worked with simply `npm install demon`, but `nodemon` was only visible in `npm list -g --depth=0` after I did `npm install -g nodemon`

Comment: Can you mark my answer as the best answer to close the thread? @palash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@ndenasie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12526657/ndemasie) said, `nodemon` isn't installed. Try running `npm install -g nodemon` then `npm run start` and it should work.